# if a cell equals any cell in a range

Tags: excel

I have an excel file:

```
A               B     C            D        |E            F
1| 27/50/4832   let   last,first   6786746  |08/29/1232   1243123
2| 25/30/9852   let   last,first   3453453  |08/23/1325   2453434
3| 05/10/9831   let   last,first   2453434  |08/03/1256   6786746
4| 15/00/9341   let   last,first   2342352  |09/45/1259   2453434
```

And I want to say

```
if a value from column f matches any from column D
then in column G write the date from E.
```

A bit of a condition here is, not everything in F is unique. If it isn't unique, we would take the most recent date. As you see above, 2453434 is repeated twice in F. So G3 would say 08/23/1325 because it clearly happened almost 100 years later.

I have some tries (obviously incredibly simplistic), that aren't working and I can't get it to even start doing what I would like. And therefore can't get to the more complicated case of the most recent date.

```
=IF(F:F=D1,E1,"")
=IF(MATCH(D1,F:F,0),E1,"")
=IF(VLOOKUP(D1,F:F,1,FALSE)=D1,E:E,"die")
```

I would rather not use vba, if possible. But am open to the suggestion.

Comment: Are those really the dates that you have? Or are those just dummy dates while the real dates you use are real dates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use something like this:

```
=INDEX(E:E,MATCH(1,(E:E=MAX(IF(F:F=D1,E:E,0)))*(F:F=D1),0))
```

assuming that your dates are correct.

Also, the above is an array formula, meaning that to make it work properly, you will have to hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> after typing in the formula.

PS: Change the range appropriately, namely the E:E and F:F. If you have 200 rows, use `E$1:E$200` and `F$1:F$200` respectively so that the formula doesn't take an eternity to calculate.

This will retrieve the latest date from column E where the value from column D matches that from F.

For instance, it will put, in G1, `08/03/1256` (assuming valid date) since F3 matches D1 and will put in G3, `08/23/1325` (assuming valid date) since both F2 and F4 matches D3, but F2 is the later date.

Comment: `assuming valid date` - I'm not sure how they could be valid dates, since excel min date is 01/01/1900. As I see they're stored as text

Comment: @simoco A valid date would be `01/04/2014` but the OP wanted to use 'fake dates' just for the sake of being an example.

Comment: I don't see where OP mentioned about this in Q

Comment: @simoco That's what I assumed to be and made it clear in my answer! xD

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that in your real data you have *correct dates*, use this one:

```
=IFERROR(LARGE(IF(D1=F:F,E:E,""),1),"")
```

with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

If you have dates like in your example above, that are out of range for excel (min date in excel `01/01/1900`)  getting max date is a real problem (actulally I'm not sure if it's really dates, since you have `09/45/1259` where `45` can't be day of month).

However, you can use this monster formula in `G1`:

```
=IFERROR(MID(LARGE(IF(D2=$F$1:$F$4,VALUE(RIGHT($E$1:$E$4,4)&LEFT($E$1:$E$4,2)&MID($E$1:$E$4,4,2)),""),1),5,2) & "/" & 
         RIGHT(LARGE(IF(D2=$F$1:$F$4,VALUE(RIGHT($E$1:$E$4,4)&LEFT($E$1:$E$4,2)&MID($E$1:$E$4,4,2)),""),1),2) & "/" &
         LEFT(LARGE(IF(D2=$F$1:$F$4,VALUE(RIGHT($E$1:$E$4,4)&LEFT($E$1:$E$4,2)&MID($E$1:$E$4,4,2)),""),1),4),"")
```

press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> to evaluate it and drag it down.
Also you can make formula shorter and faster using addtional column for `LARGE(..)`. Note that I'm using `$F$1:$F$4` instead `F:F`, because it makes formula much faster.