# If Cell Value is present in a range of Cells

Tags: excel

I have an excel file:

```
A          B          C          D          E          F
1000603    90         1000702    Chocolate  PCS  
1000965    22         1000232    Apple      BOX
1008596    56         1555254    Burger     PCS
1000323    95         1000702    Candy      BOX
1555254    63
1000702    88
```

Column A and B is my Master List of Barcodes

What I want to do is:
If a value from Column C matches from the Column A, the value in Column B will be placed in Column F

Example:

```
C         D          E          F
1000702   Chocolate  PCS        (formula that will be equal to B6) 88
```

What I have done so far was to play with the answer in this question, but I have not found the correct formula for my need: [if a cell equals any cell in a range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22796425/if-a-cell-equals-any-cell-in-a-range)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use simple `=VLOOKUP` function. Put following formula to `F1` cell then fill down as required.

```
=VLOOKUP(C1,A:B,2,FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: To handle error use `=IFERROR()` function like `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(C1,A:B,2,FALSE),"")`